# BQ24650 or BQ24620 for LiFePO battery charger | Solar powered + Grid powered

Tags: solar-cell, charger, lifepo4

I am designing a Battery Charge controller for our 12V LiFePo battery.

Power input is:

a. Solar Panel 80W @ 12V (Vopencircuit=21.33V, Vmaxpower=17.78V) OR

b. 18VDC grid power.

Either one power input will be selected at time of deployment, so PCB should be able to handle both cases.

Question: Which of the following IC is better for the application, [BQ24650](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq24650.pdf) or [BQ24620](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq24620.pdf)? What is the difference between these ICs?

Battery specs: Charge Voltage=14.3V, 4 cell Lithium Iron Phosphate, Vout=12V

This is my first time design a Solar panel powered circuit. Thank you.

Comment: BQ26450 as MPPT. Both handle LiFePO4 OK. This [BQ26450 development kit user guide](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/sluu444a/sluu444a.pdf) nay be useful.

Answer (score 2):

BQ24650 is a MPPT controller/charger for solar panel. While the BQ24620 is designed for adapter charger.

I would try the MPPT, because it is suited for panel, I guess when you will connect the DC voltage on the input, the MPPT point is trivial and it shouldn't make troubles. Anyway you can experiment with different DC voltages - higher or lower than 18V if the circuit will have weird behaviour.

It seems no problem to operate the BQ24650 from adapter:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GN7At6CLAyE